# WCF configuration Error .. service metadata cannot be accessible in visual Studio 2012

Tags: wcf, metadata

I do have the problem that if I try to start the Project with the WCF Service as the Startpage I get the following Message:
Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata.

the configuration file as the following

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
```

Comment: show mex endpoint at config

Comment: Remove name="" from behavior element. I presume this is .net 4